# Javascript check if string contains only nbsp;

Tags: javascript, string, detection, html-entities

This may be extremely trivial but I'm looking for a way to check if a string contains ONLY the html entity `nbsp;`

Example:

```
// checking if string ONLY CONTAINS nbsp;
'nbsp;' -> true
'nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;' -> true
'nbsp;nbsp; HELLO WORLD nbsp;' -> false
```

How can I go about doing so? obviously the most concise efficient method would be ideal... any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```js
const test = str => console.log(/^(?:nbsp;)+$/.test(str));
test('nbsp;');
test('nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;');
test('nbsp;nbsp; HELLO WORLD nbsp;');
```

If you want to permit the empty string as well, then change the `+` (repeat the group one or more times) to `*` (repeat the group zero or more times).

Comment: well i dont want to permit it, i want to render it invalid. thanks for the method!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way could be to use `.split` and a `Set` to check whether "nbsp;" appears in your string with other items:

```js
const check = str => new Set(str.split('nbsp;')).size == 1

console.log(check('nbsp;'));
console.log(check('nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;'));
console.log(check('nbsp;nbsp; HELLO WORLD nbsp;'));
```

**Note:** This will pick up whitespaces as well

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input1 = 'nbsp;';
const input2 = 'nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;nbsp;';
const input3 = 'nbsp;nbsp; HELLO WORLD nbsp;';

function allSpaces(str) {
    let arr = str.trim().split(';');
    arr = arr.slice(0, arr.length - 1);
    return arr.every(str => str === 'nbsp');
}

console.log(allSpaces(input1));
console.log(allSpaces(input2));
console.log(allSpaces(input3));
```